# Avoid sequential animation callback hell in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an web project where I'd like to animate the opacity of five colored divs causing them to "blink" in sequence, and the user would then click on them in the same order (like Simon says). The demo sequence starts when the user clicks a button, and the button also fades out so it can only be clicked once. My code is this (only for the demo animation, not concerned with the user response at the moment):

```
function circleBlink(elem, callback) {
  elem.animate({'opacity':'0'}, function() {
    elem.animate({'opacity':'1'}, function() {
      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
      }
    });
  });
}

function runThrough() {
  circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .red-orange'), function() {
    circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .blue'), function() {
      circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .yellow'), function() {
        circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .green'), function() {
          circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .purple'));
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

$('.start-btn').click(function() {
  $that = $(this);
  $that.animate({'opacity': '0'}, function() {
    $that.addClass('hidden');
  });
  runThrough();
  setTimeout(runThrough, 5000);

});
```

The code works fine as-is, but I would like to know if there's a less verbose/more performant/best practice way to refactor it. I am using jQuery but don't want to bring in any other animation libraries or plugins for this particular project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively:

```
function runThrough(colors, index) {
    if(index < colors.length){return;}
    circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .'+colors[index]), function() {
        runThrough(colors, index+1);
    });
}

//don't forget the init index! my bad!
runThrough(['red-orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'etc', 'etc'], 0)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with my example until I added '0' as a second arg to the call to runThrough, and put '>' instead of '<' in the if statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hellkat_ yes that is my careless

Answer (score 3):

You could create a wrapper function for `animate` that returns a Promise, and also turn `circleBlink` into a function that returns a Promise. You can also use an arrow function to avoid the uglyness of `that = this`:

```
const animateWithOpacity = (jqElm, opacity) => new Promise(resolve => {
  jqElm.animate({ opacity }, resolve);
});
async function circleBlink(elem) {
  await animateWithOpacity(elem, '0');
  await animateWithOpacity(elem, '1');
  // async function will automatically return promise that resolves when end is reached
}

async function runThrough() {
  const classes = ['red-orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple'];
  for (const className of classes) {
    await circleBlink($('.sequence-options > .' + className));
  }
}

$('.start-btn').click(function() {
  animateWithOpacity($(this), 0)
    .then(() => $(this).addClass('hidden'));
  runThrough();
  setTimeout(runThrough, 5000);
  // might also be able to `runThrough().then(runThrough)` if the timing is right
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution, unfortunately my team still isn't very comfortable with async/await. Hoping to use this as an example of how it can help them

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `var $that = $(this)` fulfills uses other than simply providing a scoped reference; it avoids executing the large amount of initialization code within creating a jQuery selection. Even with arrow functions, it's still useful to create a reference for it instead of calling it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`$.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), jQuery's version of a native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, you can chain them quite nicely without nested callbacks or recursion:

```js
$.fn.blink = function () {
  return this
    .animate({ opacity: 0 })
    .animate({ opacity: 1 })
    .promise()
}

function sequence () {
  return $.Deferred().resolve().then(function () {
    return $('.sequence-options > .red-orange').blink()
  }).then(function () {
    return $('.sequence-options > .blue').blink()
  }).then(function () {
    return $('.sequence-options > .yellow').blink()
  }).then(function () {
    return $('.sequence-options > .green').blink()
  }).then(function () {
    return $('.sequence-options > .purple').blink()
  })
}

$('.start-btn').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .animate({ opacity: 0 })
    .addClass('hidden')
    .promise()
    .then(sequence)
    .then(sequence)
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.red-orange {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start-btn">Start</button>
<div class="sequence-options">
  <div class="circle red-orange"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle yellow"></div>
  <div class="circle green"></div>
  <div class="circle purple"></div>
</div>
```

Shrinking this even further, you can pre-compute some essential references and generate each of the `.then()` functions from their respective class selectors:

```js
$.fn.blink = function () {
  return this
    .animate({ opacity: 0 })
    .animate({ opacity: 1 })
    .promise()
}

var $options = $('.sequence-options')
var selectors = ['.red-orange', '.blue', '.yellow', '.green', '.purple']
var circles = selectors.map(function (selector) {
  return $options.children(selector)
})
var animations = circles.map(function ($circle) {
  return function () {
    return $circle.blink()
  }
})

function sequence () {
  return animations.reduce(function (deferred, animation) {
    return deferred.then(animation)
  }, $.Deferred().resolve())
}

$('.start-btn').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .animate({ opacity: 0 })
    .addClass('hidden')
    .promise()
    .then(sequence)
    .then(sequence)
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.red-orange {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start-btn">Start</button>
<div class="sequence-options">
  <div class="circle red-orange"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle yellow"></div>
  <div class="circle green"></div>
  <div class="circle purple"></div>
</div>
```

Finally, with ES2017 syntax, you can take advantage of the fact that [`$.Deferred()` in jQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible) now implements the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/), and use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to make it very concise:

```js
$.fn.blink = function () {
  return this
    .animate({ opacity: 0 })
    .animate({ opacity: 1 })
    .promise()
}

const $options = $('.sequence-options')
const selectors = ['.red-orange', '.blue', '.yellow', '.green', '.purple']
const circles = selectors.map(selector => $options.children(selector))
const animations = circles.map($circle => () => $circle.blink())

async function sequence () {
  for (const animation of animations) {
    await animation()
  }
}

$('.start-btn').click(async function () {
  const $this = $(this)

  await $.when($this.animate({ opacity: 0 }))
  $this.addClass('hidden')
  await sequence()
  await sequence()
})
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.red-orange {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button class="start-btn">Start</button>
<div class="sequence-options">
  <div class="circle red-orange"></div>
  <div class="circle blue"></div>
  <div class="circle yellow"></div>
  <div class="circle green"></div>
  <div class="circle purple"></div>
</div>
```